# Orchard CMS Change Login "Widget" Title

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

So, the login form's title is "Access Denied".

How do I change this title to "Login"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view called LogOn.cshtml in the View folders of your Theme. The original shape is taken from Orchard.User/Views/LogOn.cshtml. You can copy->paste to replace it